# Using typeid for separating code execution

Tags: c++, templates, types

This question derives from the need to call legacy C routines (FFTW), which have different function names depending on type (single/double/quadruple precision), in a templated C++ class. A simple example of what I might want to do is given by this incorrect codesample:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdlib>

void fcnd(double *x) {
    *x = pow(*x, 2);
    printf("%f\n", *x);
}

void fcnf(float *x) {
    *x -= 1;
    printf("%f\n", *x);
}

template <typename T> class Class {

public:
    void fcn() {
        T *var;
        if (typeid(T) == typeid(float)) {
            var = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
        } else if (typeid(T) == typeid(double)) {
            var = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double));
        }

        *var = 1.0;

        if (typeid(T) == typeid(float)) {
            fcnf(var);
        } else if (typeid(T) == typeid(double)) {
            fcnd(var);
        }
        free(var);
    }
};

int main() {
    Class<double> x;
    Class<float> y;

    x.fcn();
    y.fcn();
}
```

GCC complains:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void Class<T>::fcn() [with T = double]': test.cpp:42:11:   required from here test.cpp:22:17: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'double*' in assignment
             var = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
                 ^ test.cpp:30:17: error: cannot convert 'double*' to 'float*' for argument '1' to 'void fcnf(float*)'
             fcnf(var);
                 ^ test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void Class<T>::fcn() [with T = float]': test.cpp:43:11:   required from here test.cpp:24:17: error: cannot convert 'double*' to 'float*' in assignment
             var = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double));
                 ^ test.cpp:32:17: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'void fcnd(double*)'
             fcnd(var);
                 ^
```

Now, I know what the error here is. My question is, why does C++ not allow this? Certainly this is safe, right? I think specialization might help here, is that always the correct approach?

Comment: Using `typeid` like that is usually frowned upon and considered a bad design. And why do you need a pointer instead of simply `T var;`? You can use the address-of operator `&` to pass the variable as a pointer, or better yet use *references*. And then use function overloading to have the compiler pick the correct function to be called. That means your function body could be as simple as `T var = 1; func(var);`

Comment: I'm using a pointer because that's what I'll need (I think) in the more complicated code that will be calling FFTW.

Comment: While pointers can be needed in a few situations, they are otherwise in the majority of cases in modern C++ the wrong solution. Try to make a pointer-less solution using references and overloading instead. And if it turns out it will not work, *then* you can use pointers, but still use overloading. And you still don't need to use `typeid`. And definitely not using `malloc` (use `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`). And use the standard `std::cout` instead of `printf` for type-safe output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling a function based on the template argument can be done as follows in C++17:

```
template <typename T> class Class
{
public:
    void fcn()
    {
        // one line can do it
        T* var{ reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(*var))) };

        *var = 1.0;

        // C++17's if constexpr does exactly what you need
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        {
            fcnf(var);
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        {
            fcnd(var);
        }

        free(var);
    }
};
```

If you don't have C++17 available, you can use a dispatcher based on `T` with template specializations or just a simple overloaded function.

```
auto set(float* f) noexcept
{
    return fcnf(f);
}

auto set(double* d) noexcept
{
    return fcnd(d);
}

template <typename T> class Class
{
public:
    void fcn() 
    {
        T* var{ reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(*var))) };
        *var = 1.0;
        set(var); // there's a reason we have function overloading in C++
        free(var);
    }
};
```

Note: I hope in your real code you check the result of calling `std::malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful response. I don't have C++17 yet so the followup is appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasAnderson No problem. Please remember to accept the answer if it has solved your issue.

Comment: Actually could you explain (or name at least, so I can look it up) the definition of 'var' in your second example. I don't believe I have seen that syntax before. In particular it is surprising to me that you can reference the size of a variable at the time you are declaring it.

Comment: @ThomasAnderson you can replace `sizeof(*var)` with `sizeof(T)` if you want. I'm not sure, but I believe that `var`'s type is already set right before the initializer, so the compiler has access to the required type information for the `sizeof(*var)` call.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a template class, why not just define overloaded functions:

```
void fcn(double& x) {
    fcnd(&x);
}

void fcn(float& x) {
    fcnf(&x);
}
```

Also, if the names of the functions only differ by some standard set of suffixes (to denote the type), you could even use macros to easily define overloads all available functions:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
    Some C functions, actually defined elsewhere...
*/

void fcnd(double *x) {
    *x = pow(*x, 2);
}

void fcnf(float *x) {
    *x -= 1;
}

/*
    Some macros to simplify things
*/

#define define_overloaded_function_for(name, type, suffix)\
void name(type& x) { name##suffix(&x); }

#define define_overloaded_functions_for(name)\
define_overloaded_function_for(name, float, f)\
define_overloaded_function_for(name, double, d)\
/* define_overloaded_function_for(name, long double, ld) */

/*
    Define some functions
*/
define_overloaded_functions_for(fcn);
/* ...etc... */

int main(void) {
    float a = 705;
    double b = 2465;
    cout << "~ a ~" << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
    fcn(a);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << "~ b ~" << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    fcn(b);
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am working on an existing (large) codebase where the templates already exist and are necessary to avoid code reuse. But yea the suggestion is a good one